# Continuity of solution to 2nd Order PDE w.r.t. the coefficients

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, approximation-theory, continuity

I am considering the following 2nd order PDE :

On a domain $R$, for some $r > 0$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i, j = 1}^{K}\gamma_{i}\gamma_{j}U_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x) + \sum_{i = 1}^{K}\frac{\gamma_{0}\gamma_{i}}{x_{0}}U_{x_{i}}(x) - rU(x) = -rg\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)
\end{equation*}
\begin{align}
\gamma_{i} &= \gamma_{i}(a, b, x)\,\,\textrm{is Lipschitz continuous}\,\,\,\textrm{for each}\,\,i \in \{0,1,...,K\}\\
g &= g(a, b)\,\,\,\textrm{is a Lipschitz continuous function}
\end{align}
where, with $DU(x) = \big(U_{x_{1}}(x),...,U_{x_{K}}(x)\big)$,
\begin{align*}
a &= a\big(x, DU(x)\big)\\
b &= b\big(x, DU(x)\big)
\end{align*}

I am considering the following iteration to show an exitence of $U$ to the above PDE:

1. Pick any continuous functions $a_{0}(x)$ and $b_{0}(x)$ on $R$
2. Plug them into $\gamma_{i}(a_{0}(x), b_{0}(x), x) = \gamma_{i}^{0}(x)$ and $g(a_{0}(x), b_{0}(x)) = g_{0}(x)$
3. Solve the linear elliptic 2nd order PDE (1) on $R$ with $\gamma_{i}^{0}(x)$ and $g_{0}(x)$. Let the solution $U_{0}(x)$
4. Let $a_{1}(x) = a(x, DU_{0}(x))$ and $b_{1}(x) = b(x, DU_{0}(x))$ be continuous functions w.r.t $x \in R$
5. Plug them into $\gamma_{i}(a_{1}(x), b_{1}(x), x) = \gamma_{i}^{1}(x)$ and $g(a_{1}(x), b_{1}(x)) = g_{1}(x)$
6. Solve the linear elliptic 2nd order PDE (1) on $R$ with $\gamma_{i}^{1}(x)$ and $g_{1}(x)$. Let the solution $U_{1}(x)$
7. Iterate...

[QUESTION]

**For the convergence of $\{U_{n}\}$ on $R$ to a limit,**

**I want to show something like a continuity property of the linear solution $U_{n}$ on the coefficients $\{\gamma^{n}_{i}, g_{n}\}_{i=0}^{K}$.**

**Could anyone suggest me some references for this question?**

Comment: This doesn’t look elliptic to me. The matrix $\gamma_i\gamma_j$ is not positive definite.

Comment: @DeaneYang Dear Yang, thanks for your comment. I am considering to impose any assumption that makes $\{\gamma_{i}\gamma_{j}\}_{i,j}$ a positive definite matrix so that the PDE (1) is uniformly elliptic in any compact subset of $R$. Do you think if this is reasonable for my approach?

Comment: It’s never elliptic.

Comment: @DeaneYang Hi. Could you give me any hint why you think that it is NEVER elliptic? I am supposing that $x \Gamma x > \epsilon$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{K}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ in any compact subset of $R$ where $\Gamma = \{\gamma_{i}\gamma_{j}\}_{i,j}^{K}$, which guarantees that $\Gamma$ is a positive definite matrix. I am focusing on $a$ and $b$ that satisfy the ellipticity of $\Gamma$ at each step of my iterations. Furthermore, at each step of iteration, since each $\gamma_{i}$ and $g$ is only a function of $x \in R$, it is a linear second order PDE...

Comment: Have you checked whether the kernel of the matrix contains only $0$?

Comment: @DeaneYang I am sorry that I forgot to mention that $\gamma_{i}$ is not a scalar but a $d$-dimensional vector with $d \geq K$ and $\{\gamma_{i}\}_{i}^{K}$ is linearly independent. This is one of the conditions that I imposed on the PDE (1). So, the kernel of $\Gamma = \{\gamma_{i}^{T}\cdot\gamma_{j}\}_{i,j}^{K}$ contains only $0$.

Comment: In that case, the PDE is indeed elliptic. Is $x_0 \ne 0$? If so, then this is a quasilinear elliptic PDE. Your approach will lead to solutions under some assumptions. You might want to consult the book by Gilbarg and Turdinger. if $x_0 = 0$ somewhere in $\R$, then more care is needed.

Comment: @DeaneYang Thank you very much for your comments. Yes. I know it is a quasi-linear elliptic PDE. $x = 0$ is on the boundary $\partial R$ and, for each $n \geq 0$, every $a_{n}(x)$ and $b_{n}(x)$ has a constant value at $x = 0$. My question is, under which conditions, **the sequence of solutions to the LINEAR PDE at each step has a limit.** I believe that it depends on the continuity property of each solution $U_{n}(x)$ to the coefficients $\gamma_{i}$ and $g$. I am checking Gilbarg and Trudinger, but it would be appreciated if you could suggest another references. Thank You!